# Single Light switch to turn on/off based on computer program running

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi, computers

Brand new here so please be gentle lol Im interested in creating a light switch that turns on/off based on whether a computer program is running (Mac for now). I'm not entirely sure what components I need but think if I have that portion, I can take it from there.

So far, I'm thinking of connecting a USB-C to a (and this is the part I don't know) either to a microcontroller or to the switch itself. Not sure if that architecture will work. Later on, I'd want to have a wireless lighting device that will be controlled by bluetooth, most likely through a raspberry pi.

Any and all help/resources/suggestions/info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome!  Questions on stack exchange sites must be highly specific, and purchase recommendation questions in particular are banned.  Start by making your own survey of what is on the market (if only for ideas), including things like USB-controlled relays (ideally packaged for mains use), plug relays controlled by crude RF means like 433 MHz OOK, and plug relays with WIFI and IP network control.  Many of the "products" have been reverse engineered on hacking sites to allow command injection, if you chose to build something from scratch you will have to be very careful of mains power safety.

Comment: Ethernet or Wi-Fi is usually easier than USB for hobby projects. Unless you can use a USB device that someone else made, like a USB/serial adapter. In fact a lot of projects use USB/serial adapters. Arduinos have them built-in.